# Removing date from datetime column R

Tags: r, date, lubridate, posixct, strptime

I have a column of times in my excel (.xlsx) dataset (named "necro_time"; formatted `%H:%M:%S`). When I import my data ("test") using the *read_excel* function (library readxl) it automatically formats my time column as a POSIXct with the format `Y-M-D H:M:S`, essentially applying a random date of "1899-12-31" to each of my times. When I use the `strptime` function to try and strip away the date to keeping only the time it returns `NA`s. I have tried all combinations of datetime formats, as well as making new columns and trying to parse the datetime that way (not what I want to do anyways) and nothing is working.

Advice?

**structure of my dataframe:**

```
> str(test)


Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1051 obs. of  43 variables:

 ...

 $ necro_date               : POSIXct, format: "1900-01-01" "2018-12-19" "2018-12-19" ...

 $ necro_time               : POSIXct, format: "1899-12-31 23:59:00" "1899-12-31 11:12:00" "1899-12-31 11:03:00" ...
```

**code I am trying to run:**

```
test$necro_time = (strptime(test$necro_time, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

**returns:**

```
> str(test)

Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1051 obs. of  43 variables:

...

 $ necro_date               : POSIXct, format: "1900-01-01" "2018-12-19" "2018-12-19" ...

 $ necro_time               : POSIXct, format: NA NA NA ...
```

I have also tried:

```
test$necro_time = as.POSIXct(strptime(test$necro_time, format = "%Y-%M-%D"))

test$necro_time = as.POSIXct(strptime(test$necro_time, format = "%Y-%M-%D %H:%M:%S"))

test$necro_time = strptime(test$necro_time, format = "%I:%M %p")
```

all return a full column of `NA`s. I feel like its something simple but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi K W! Does `strftime(test$necro_time, "%H:%M:%S")` do what you want? If that doesn't work, please share a snippet of your data frame using `dput()`, so we can help you better.

Comment: Champion! Thank you so much.